# How to determine on which side two rectangles intersect?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to implement a function that detects if two rectangles intersect, that is if they "touch" without using the `Rectangle.IntersectsWith` function.
The reason for this is because I want to determine on which side the collision happens with respect to the "hero" object, but it doesn't work.

```
public bool[] Collisions(Rectangle hero, Rectangle rect)
{
    bool hitSomethingAbove = false;
    bool hitSomethingBelow = false;
    bool hitSomethingOnTheRight = false;
    bool hitSomethingOnTheLeft = false;

    if (hero.Left < rect.Right) // collision on left side
    {
       hitSomethingOnTheLeft = true;
    }
    if (hero.Right > rect.Left) // collision on right side
    {
       hitSomethingOnTheRight = true;
    }
    if (hero.Top < rect.Bottom) // collision on top
    {
       hitSomethingAbove = true;
    }
    if (hero.Bottom > rect.Top) // collision on bottom
    {
       hitSomethingBelow = true;
    }

    return new bool[] { hitSomethingAbove, hitSomethingBelow, 
        hitSomethingOnTheRight, hitSomethingOnTheLeft };
}
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn´t work"? Do you get any exception? Unexpected behavour? What happens, when you execute that code?

Comment: Did you invent math yourself? Looks wrong to me. Are you trying to *snap* rectangles or what?

Comment: Well, it's for a simple 2D game and all "physical" boundaries are in terms of rectangles and so is the playable character. But because of this function he cannot move neither can he fall. It's like he's just stuck in one place.

Comment: can we see the code where this Collisions check is done please

Comment: Just an asside: instead of returning an array of 4 bools, why not have a single value (best an enum) that indicates the direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use `Rectangle.Intersect` method:

```
public bool[] Collisions(Rectangle hero, Rectangle rect)
{
    var intersection = Rectangle.Intersect(hero, rect);
    if(intersection.IsEmpty){
        return new []{ false, false, false, false };
    }

    bool hitSomethingAbove = hero.Top == intersection.Top;
    bool hitSomethingBelow = hero.Bottom == intersection.Bottom;
    bool hitSomethingOnTheRight = hero.Right == intersection.Right;
    bool hitSomethingOnTheLeft = hero.Left == intersection.Left;

    return new bool[] 
    { 
        hitSomethingAbove, 
        hitSomethingBelow, 
        hitSomethingOnTheRight, 
        hitSomethingOnTheLeft, 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem that your code has is that all the tests assume the hero is already in a certain position relative to the other rectangle. For example:

```
if (hero.Left < rect.Right) // collision on left side
```

Assumes that the hero was already to the right of the other rectangle prior to this check. If the hero was already on the left of the other rectangle, your test is now claiming there was a collision to the right of the rectangle (ie, collision on the hero's left side, as per your code comment).

So your logic is broken here.

Comment: So I would need some additional checks? Like say

if (hero.Left < rectangle.Right && rectangle.Right < hero.Right ) // for left